# Compare latest indicator value with target value in AWS Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, visualization, amazon-quicksight, import-from-excel

I have several rows of data on KPIs (monthly basis) and want to compare the latest month (e.g. March 2023) with a specific target value that is the same for each month.
Ideally, I want to use the KPI graph of AWS Quicksight (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/kpi.html), but only comparing two values: the latest indicator value with a target value.
I already tried using the lastValue function, but it does not seem to create a column of the same values:
lastValue({Indicator}, [{Date} ASC])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding a "calculated field" to the data in which both columns, the indicator value and target value, are compared